# C# Validate XML against XSD

Tags: c#, xsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xml validation using XSD schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572853/xml-validation-using-xsd-schema)

I have generated some XML using some C#. I need to see if that XML validates against an XSD file. Is there a way to do this in C#? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 19):

See this question:

[Xml validation using XSD schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572853/xml-validation-using-xsd-schema)

It shows that all you need to do is set the right option when creating your XmlReader:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Schemas.Add(null, xsdFilePath);
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler(settings_ValidationEventHandler);

var reader = XmlReader.Create(source, settings);
```

You will now get information on validation errors in `settings_ValidationEventHandler` and the document load will be aborted if required.