# Validating a xml during run-time in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xml validation using XSD schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572853/xml-validation-using-xsd-schema)
>   [Validating an XML against referenced XSD in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751511/validating-an-xml-against-referenced-xsd-in-c-sharp)

I have to validate a xml against a schema during runtime. The xml is retrieved as a string and I have the xsd file added to a schema folder under the project. May you please help me with this scenario? The project is in .NET c# platform

Thanks!